# new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create() failing in Junit 4 testing

Tags: gson, junit4

Due to vulnerability in Gson, we upgraded the version of com.google.code.gson from 2.8.0 to 2.9.0.
The code compiled fine but when we ran the Junit(Junit 4) test case it failed at the line with the below exception.
Need some guidance in fixing this, any response is appreciated.

code line: `Gson gson =` *new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();*
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at com.google.gson.Gson.(Gson.java:187)
at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.create(GsonBuilder.java:572)
....
...
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: The constructor of the internal Gson class `ConstructorConstructor` was changed in previous versions. Most likely something is messing with your classpath causing it load some classes from an older Gson version. Without more information (e.g. a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) it is difficult to tell what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Hi @Marcono1234 , Yes the constructor is changed but I have removed all the old gson version from maven repository and still facing this issue. Moreover this happening in our Dev environment jenkins build too. Not sure what is wrong with this.

Comment: I assume this is something specific to your build setup. Could you please try to create a minimal, reproducible example? Often during the process of creating such an example, one notices what is causing the issue. You could try commenting out all plugins one by one in the POM until it starts to work as expected, and then further investigate what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Marcono1234: Thank you for your time and comment. I figured out what is causing the issue. It's the AEM Uber Jar. Things are working fine until I added the Uber Jar dependency. We are using AEM 6.4.8 version and it seems that the Uber jar version 6.4.8 using Gson transitive dependency of 2.8.2 version and while running the test case it is picking the version 2.8.2.

I fixed it by simply changing the order of including dependency where Gson dependency is included first and after that Uber Jar dependency. Showing sample below. That solves my issue of test case failing.

Comment: <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
<artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
<version>6.4.8</version>
<classifier>apis</classifier>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.13.2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: Thanks for the update. Maybe it would be useful if you answered your own question with that information. That way others stumbling over this question will find this solution.